# How to stop previous interval and start new interval timer in C#

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

How to stop previous `interval(elapsedEvent)` and start new `interval(elapsedEvent)` timer in C#.

Ex: I had interval with one hour with `interval(elapsedEvent)` , later user changed to two hours with `interval(elapsedEvent)`.

While I tried to change one hour to two hour `interval (elapsedEvent)`, it is coming for both one and two hours  as well.

Need to change the `interval (elapsedEvent)` of timer what I given.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you share the code you struggling with

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to ask a question that makes it easy for those who want to help to pinpoint the source of the problem.